# Can someone help me identify this spiral staircase system?

Tags: stairs, carpentry

I am thinking of buying [this spiral staircase](http://boston.craigslist.org/sob/hsh/3396259183.html) to use to get to our loft, but was curious if any of you could identify the type of staircase that it is.

[image]
[image]

What is pictured is the section that sits on the floor, supposedly after that each step is a separate bolt-on unit.  Also odd about this setup is that there is no center pole.  I cannot seem to find a photo of a similar setup all put together.  The guy that is selling this does not know that much about it.

I would go check it out in person, however it is 3 hours away!  I welcome any information you guys can offer.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the seller what type of staircase it is?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a spiral staircase, but rather a helical staircase.  The difference is the lack of the centre pole (As you noticed.  It's otherwise known as a newel) and that it has handrails on both sides, whereas a spiral staircase only has a handrail on the outside.

I was able to find [this example](http://www.archiexpo.com/prod/essegi-scale/helicoidal-staircases-with-lateral-stringer-metal-frame-and-wooden-steps-56904-654092.html) of what appears to be a similar design, though it looks wider than your's.